# Implementing Android Settings Menu to Change Main Activity's layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

For the app I'm making I added a "Settings" menu. So far, I've gotten a checkbox option to show up. And the preference is maintained (check box is checked or unchecked is remembered).

However, in my code it does nothing. I'd like the UX to be:

1. User goes to settings menu
2. User checks (True) to "Dark Background?"
3. The background of my RelativeLayout becomes dark when the user returns to the MainActivity.
4. The background *remains* dark when the user opens the app again in the future.
5. When unchecked the background returns to the original background.

I've looked through many tutorials and the android documentation and new boston videos, etc. But none of the code I have implemented has been able to do this. It either crashes or does nothing.

Can someone explain simply how to do this? I can't imagine it is that difficult.

Thanks!

Comment: wheres the code that you tried? wheres the stack trace where it crashed?

Comment: It doesn't crash. And the code I tried doesn't work, so I'm assuming it isn't correct as everything else works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate method of your Activity, get the value of your preference, then act accordingly based on what is set (here is pseudo-code):

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);  
    RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);

    // get value from shared prefs  to variable sharedPrefValue

    if (sharedPrefValue)
        relLayout.setBackgroundColor(colors.black);

}
```

Comment: The commented portion is the portion I'm asking about. I was actually changing the background by calling mBackground.setBackgroundColor(colors.black).

Comment: I fixed my answer (so it is clearer, based on your usage, think this should help).  Good luck.

Comment: This code didn't work. I used the above code as well as:

  SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String mDarkBackground = sharedPref.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_BACKGROUND_COLOR, "");

Comment: Thought you were asking how to set the background, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the layout based on the settings easily, but the change would only be seen when restarting the activity

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //...
    int mylayout = R.layout.main;
    if (preferenceIsTrue)
        mylayout = R.layout.mainDark;
    setContentView(mylayout);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Then how do I get it to update immediately after returning from settings?

Comment: And also, I'd like to maintain the original layout files, i don't want to create a new layout for each possible layout change I want to implement optionally.

Answer (score 0):

They answer to my question:

Used:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Boolean prefCheckBox = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(
            "background_checkbox", false);
```

and then used prefCheckBox to check if its checked.

Also, in order to make sure my background was set on return from the settings menu, I added it to the OnActivityResult() method.